# Virtuoso: st_intersects() distance between points does not match with precision parameter

Tags: sparql, virtuoso, linked-data, geosparql

The [LinkedGeoData](http://linkedgeodata.org/) site has some examples of SPARQL queries. One [example](http://linkedgeodata.org/OSM) says it retrieves all amenities 100m from Leipzig Central Station. However, the [SPARQL query](http://linkedgeodata.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Flinkedgeodata.org&qtxt=Prefix%20lgdo%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Flinkedgeodata.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0D%0APrefix%20geom%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fgeovocab.org%2Fgeometry%23%3E%0D%0APrefix%20ogc%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.opengis.net%2Font%2Fgeosparql%23%3E%0D%0APrefix%20owl%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2002%2F07%2Fowl%23%3E%0D%0A%0D%0ASelect%20*%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%3Fs%0D%0A%20%20%20%20owl%3AsameAs%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FLeipzig_Hauptbahnhof%3E%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20geom%3Ageometry%20[%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20ogc%3AasWKT%20%3Fsg%0D%0A%20%20%20%20]%20.%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%3Fx%0D%0A%20%20%20%20a%20lgdo%3AAmenity%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Fl%20%3B%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20geom%3Ageometry%20[%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20ogc%3AasWKT%20%3Fxg%0D%0A%20%20%20%20]%20.%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Filter%28bif%3Ast_intersects%20%28%3Fsg%2C%20%3Fxg%2C%200.1%29%29%20.%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=0&debug=on) results have much more distance than 100m from the Central Station.

The example's text is wrong, or the function is wrong?

Ps: I have verified the distance between the points using the [OpenStreetMap site](https://www.openstreetmap.org/).

Comment: Also raised on Github as an [issue on the LinkedGeoData project](https://github.com/GeoKnow/LinkedGeoData/issues/34). As noted there, the issue appears likely to be resolved by January 2020 commits to the Virtuoso engine underlying the LinkedGeoData site, requiring update to that site/engine by its admins. In other words, I believe this question is not appropriate for StackOverflow.